# replace comma and double quotes enclosed within double quotes in csv file using Node js

Tags: node.js, csv

Input 1 :
input: 48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB,TW,DC,PL)"

output: 48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB TW DC PL)"

Input 12:
input: 48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB,TW,"DC,PL)"   <= single double quote inside double quote

output: 48,"LHT0019","TEST COUNT (HB TW DC PL)"

How could I replace comma inside double quote using nodejs

Answer (score 3):

How I would attack this problem is by first converting the CSV to JSON with something like `csvtojson`. Then with the JSON you can convert it easily to an object and replace the values that you want to replace.